# PHP Script: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php

I am getting the following error in my browser when trying to run this script:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\wamp\www\server2.php on line 35
```

Note: Line 35 is the last line in the script. Sorry I am very new to PHP

```
  <?php
      // get the command
      $command = $_REQUEST['command'];

      // determine which command will be run
      if($command == "getAnimalList") {
        // return a list of animals
        echo "bird,dog,cat,cow,sheep";
      } else if($command == "getAnimalSound") {
        // get the animal parameter and send the right response
    $animal = $_REQUEST['cat'];

    // fetch the sound of the animal from the database
    $username = "root"; $password = ""; $hostname = "localhost"; 

    //connection to the database
    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
      or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";


    //select a database to work with
    $selected = mysql_select_db("rosslocalhost1",$dbhandle) 
      or die("Could not select examples");

    //execute the SQL query and try to return a record
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT sound FROM animalsounds WHERE name='$animal'");

    if (!$result) {
        echo 'Dont know' .mysql_error();
        exit;
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row['sound'];
    ?>
```

Comment: You've missed a closing bracket.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Any decent code editor should warn you about unbalanced brackets.

Comment: also, whenever you put something in brackets ident it properly!, much easier to debug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've missed the closing bracket in the `elseif` statement of `if($command == "getAnimalList")`

```
<?php
// get the command
$command = $_REQUEST['command'];

// determine which command will be run
if($command == "getAnimalList") {
  // return a list of animals
  echo "bird,dog,cat,cow,sheep";
} else if($command == "getAnimalSound") {
  // get the animal parameter and send the right response
  $animal = $_REQUEST['cat'];

  // fetch the sound of the animal from the database
  $username = "root"; $password = ""; $hostname = "localhost"; 

  //connection to the database
  $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
    or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
  echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";


  //select a database to work with
  $selected = mysql_select_db("rosslocalhost1",$dbhandle) 
    or die("Could not select examples");

  //execute the SQL query and try to return a record
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT sound FROM animalsounds WHERE name='$animal'");

  if (!$result) {
    echo 'Dont know' .mysql_error();
    exit;
  }
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  echo $row['sound'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code properly indented. You did not properly close `else if ($command == "getAnimalSound")`

```
<?php
// get the command
$command = $_REQUEST['command'];

// determine which command will be run
if ($command == "getAnimalList") {
    // return a list of animals
    echo "bird,dog,cat,cow,sheep";
} else if ($command == "getAnimalSound") {
    // get the animal parameter and send the right response
    $animal = $_REQUEST['cat'];
}

// fetch the sound of the animal from the database
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";


//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("rosslocalhost1", $dbhandle) or die("Could not select examples");

//execute the SQL query and try to return a record
$result = mysql_query("SELECT sound FROM animalsounds WHERE name='$animal'");

if (!$result) {
    echo 'Dont know' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['sound'];
?>
```